# Improper integral of bounded functions over bounded open interval

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

Suppose $(a,b)$ is an open and bounded interval of $\mathbb{R}$. Also, let $$f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$$ be a bounded function. Set $\tilde{f}:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ as the function $$\tilde{f}(x)=\begin{cases} f(x)\qquad x \in (a,b)\\\alpha \qquad x=a\\\beta \qquad x=b\end{cases}.$$ Is it true that if $\tilde{f}$ is Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$ then the improper integral of $f$ over $(a,b)$ converge and $$\int_{a}^{b}f=\int_{a}^{b}\tilde{f}\qquad ?$$

Note that the improper integral of $f$ over $(a,b)$, provided that $f$ is riemann integrable on any compact subinterval $[c,d]\subset (a,b)$, is defined as $$\int_{a}^{b}f=\lim_{m\to a^+}\int_{m}^{c}f+\lim_{M\to b^-}\int_{c}^{M}f$$ where $c\in (a,b)$ is arbitrary.

**Personal attempt**
Since $\tilde{f}$ is riemann integrable over $[a,b]$ then it's riemann integrable over any $[c,d]\subset (a,b)$. But $\tilde{f}=f$ on such compact intervals. So $f$ is riemann integrable over any $[c,d]\subset (a,b)$. Then, for any fixed $c\in (a,b)$ one has $$\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=\lim_{m\to a^+}\int_{m}^{c}f(t)dt+\lim_{M\to b^-}\int_{c}^{M}f(t)dt=\lim_{m\to a^+}\int_{m}^{c}\tilde{f}(t)dt+\lim_{M\to b^-}\int_{c}^{M}\tilde{f}(t)dt=\int_{a}^{c}\tilde{f}+\int_{c}^{b}\tilde{f}=\int_{a}^{b}\tilde{f}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct except for the fact that you need to justify the last step (the use of second last '$=$' sign). It is based on the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus a part of which says that *if a function $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ and if $F(x) =\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$ then the function $F$ is continuous on $[a, b] $*.

This also shows that the notion of improper integral for bounded functions on bounded intervals is superfluous (but perhaps attractive to many as some questions on this website suggest). The usual (or shall we say *proper*) Riemann integral is powerful enough to deal with bounded functions on bounded intervals and this is a precondition for the definition of Riemann integral. For example the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\sin(1/x)\,dx$ is not improper but $\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2)^{-1/2}\,dx$ is improper (and *important at the same time*).

Comment: yes, sir. I forgot to write it. So, if I well understood, the same reasoning applies to any bounded function $f:[a,b]\setminus\{c_1,\dots,c_n\}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is NOT defined at a finite number of points $c_1,\dots,c_n$ within $[a,b]$. If $\tilde{f}$ is a new function such that $\tilde{f}=f$ on $[a,b]\setminus\{c_1,\dots,c_n\}$ and anything else on $\{c_1,\dots,c_n\}$ then if $\tilde{f}$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ also the improper integral of $f$ on $[a,b]$ converge. Right?

Comment: @eleguitar: I view such integrals as proper. There is nothing extra in defining them via limit of an integral. If your function is undefined at a finite number of point then define them in any manner at those points and then integrate the resulting based. But in general one can't modify a function at an infinite number of points without affecting its Riemann integrability or the value of its integral.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Just last question: is it the same if I replace $\{c_1,\dots,c_n\}$ with any $E\subset[a,b]$ which has Lebesgue measure zero? I think the answer is no. I would like to extend Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann Integrability to function that are not necessarily defined on every point of $[a,b]$.

Comment: @eleguitar: the measure zero sets are quite different beasts. In terms of cardinality they can be uncountable like Cantor set. To use Lebesgue criterion the right approach is to ensure a definition of the function on full interval $[a, b] $ and then check the set of discontinuities. Why do you want to deal with integrating functions which are undefined at some points?

Comment: @eleguitar: just to let you know, the improper integrals were invented not to deal with functions undefined at certain points, but rather to deal with unbounded functions and / or unbounded intervals.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. My question arises because of in studying partial differential equations we deal with a bounded function $f$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (not necessarily defined at each point of $\mathbb{R}$)  and a $v \in C^1{(\mathbb{R})}$ with compact support and say that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}fv$ always exist. I would like to prove it without use Lebesgue measure theory.

Comment: @eleguitar: then your best hope is that the function is undefined at only a finite number of points. Otherwise consider switching to Lebesgue integrals. For Lebesgue sets of measure zero don't matter

Comment: yes, but I think I also need $f$ to be continuous at each point except a set of Lebesgue measure zero to prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}fv$ always exist without using Lebesgue integrals: in this way even if $f$ is not defined at a finite number of points but it's set of discontinuities has Lebesgue measure 0, then $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}fv=\int_{-M}^{M}fv$ always exist because $fv$ is bounded on $[-M,M]$ and it's set of discontinuities has Lebesgue measure 0. Am I right?

Comment: I mean, if I only know that $f$ is bounded and defined at each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (except possibly a finite number of points) and $v \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ with compact support, then I need extra hypothesis on the number of discontinuities of $f$ to certainly state that the improper Riemann integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}fv$ exist (without using lebesgue measure theory).